# Sub-delegate Reverse DNS Performance?

Tags: ip, internal-dns, reverse-dns

I am currently working on a network with multiple subnets. So far I have implemented one reverse DNS entry that is a monolithic 10.* record covering everything. Is there any benefit or performance boost for creating a granular structure allowing look-ups to occur quicker? Or is this more work than I need to perform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking this is more work than you need to perform -- Most DNS servers can handle a /8 dumped in one file without batting an eyelash in terms of performance.

Having said that, traditionally reverse zones (for IPv4) are broken out as Class C (/24) netblocks -- `C.B.A.IN-ADDR.ARPA` (because dots are the hierarchy delimiter in DNS names, and there used to be a similar hierarchy in Class A/B/C IP addresses).
That also has the benefit of keeping the zone file "small" (250ish entries), which can be easier for admins (and some badly written DNS management user interfaces) to read & manage.